# Вопрос по паттерну Repository в ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, шаблоны-проектирования

Такой вопрос. Допустим у меня есть обобщенный интерфейс **IRepository**. В котором определенные методы. Есть обобщенный класс **Repository**, который реализует интерфейс **IRepository**. И допустим мне нужно так же создать какой-нибудь специфический запрос в БД у модели **Product**. Для этого я создаю интерфейс **IProductRepository**, который наследует интерфейс **IRepository**, и объявляю в нем специфический метод. Теперь так же создаю класс **ProductRepository**, который реализует интерфейс **IProductRepository**. Получается в этом классе мне нужно реализовать методы как из интерфейса **IRepository**, так и спец.метод из **IProductRepository**. Как мне здесь поступить? Если реализация методов из **IRepository** не будет отличаться от реализации в **Repository**, то могу ли я через внедрение зависимостей создать поле в классе **ProductRepository** типа **Repository**, и у него вызывать методы, чтобы не загромождать код? Или это наоборот плохо? И будет ли работать? Как в общем поступать в таких ситуациях?
Пример того что я имею ввиду:

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<T>
{
    public string GetById(int id);
}

public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T>
{
    public string GetById(int id)
    {
        string line = $"Repository<T>: {id}";
        return line;
    }
}

public interface IProductRepository : IRepository<Product>
{
    public string GetName();
}

public class ProductRepository : IProductRepository
{
    private readonly Repository<Product> _repository;

    public ProductRepository(Repository<Product> repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }

    public string GetById(int id)
    {
        return _repository.GetById(id);
    }

    public string GetName()
    {
        return "My name Meliodas";
    }
}
```

Comment: ProductRepo от Repository нельзя унаследовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Очевидный ответ: наследовать `ProductRepository` и от класса `Repository<Product>` и от интерфейса `IProductRepository`.

Есть, правда, вопрос — зачем делать общий интерфейс репозиториев. У них, как правило, мало общего, разве что метод `GetById`, но с тем же успехом можно все сушности наследовать от базового класса `Entity` с единственным полем `Id`.

В целом, на некое пересечение методов, совсем не очевидно, что репозитории или сущности должны образовывать иерархию. Да и реализации `GetById` могут отличаться довольно сильно и требовать переопределения в каждом дочернем классе.

Подумайте, зачем оно вам.

Comment: ну как будто бы CRUD операции одинаковы у всех моделей: GetAll(),GetByID(),Create(),Delete(),Update(). Но у определенных нужно специфические методы создать. Я новичок в этом, и вроде бы в моем "проекте" это уменьшит количество кода...

Comment: @Андрей, при проектировании системы полезно идти от пользовательских историй. CRUD неплохо описывает суть операций, но детали там различаются. Вот где-то есть `GetByID`, а где-то нет и не может быть. Где-то надо удалять по одной записи, а где-то — сразу несколько. У каких-то сущностей может быть несколько разных методов `Create`, да даже если и один, его желательно делать с явными параметрами-полями.

Если вы изучаете варианты, то всё нормально. Попробуйте на своей задаче и решите, больше или меньше кода приходится писать. Просто обратите внимание, что наследование не обязательно.